# Price/1000*38 not showing when price is more than 500

Tags: php

Below is the code I have, it should take the price of a product then divide by 1000 then times by 38 to get and print the lease_price for products over £500. However, all it does it print NA, even when the product is over £500 it still shows NA. I don't know what is wrong with this? As far as I know this should work.

```
<p> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> <b>Lease To Buy Price:</b>
<span>
<?php 
  $tempPrice = str_replace(',',"", $price); //gets rid of "," 
  $tempPrice = substr($tempPrice,1); //removes currency from the front
  $tempPrice = floatval($tempPrice); //converts to double from string
  if($special > 0) 
  { 
    $lease_price = (($special/1000)*38);  
  } 
  else 
  { 
    $lease_price = (($tempPrice/1000)*38); 
  }  
  $lease_price = $this->currency->format($lease_price);
  if($tempPrice > 500) 
  {
    echo $lease_price;
  }
  else 
  {
    echo 'NA';
  }
?>
</span></p>
```

Comment: What does $this->currency->format($lease_price); return?

Comment: to me $lease_price works. maybe str_replace or substr or floatval aren't used correctly

Comment: It works fine for me: http://ideone.com/xUqwOY

Comment: @Barmar Here is where I've implemented, it's not working here, do you know what could be stopping it? http://www.framec.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=50

Comment: There's no way for me to see you PHP code from that, all I can see is the output.

Comment: I commented out the call to `$this->currency->format` in my code, since I don't know what that does. Do you have the same problem without that?

Comment: What do you see if you `echo $tempPrice;`?

Comment: I've commented it out and it still shows NA.

Comment: @Barmar Here's the tpl file http://pastebin.com/vemG3EQm and here's the php file http://pastebin.com/Ghq6MBZ9

Comment: @Barmar When I add <?php echo $tempPrice; ?> it does not print anything.

Comment: The format of `$price` is probably not what you think it is. I'm guessing that the pound character is encoded in UTF-8 which means that you have **two** bytes in front of the number.

Comment: @NisseEngström I updated this line: `$tempPrice = substr($tempPrice,2);` but it doesn't change anything, the product still prints NA

Comment: What's the output of `echo bin2hex ($price), "\n";`?

Comment: @NisseEngström Nothing outputs

Comment: Your problem is not in the code you have posted. Please reduce your program to a **minimal complete** and **verifiable** example ([**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that still exhibits the problem. You may find that the process of reducing the program often helps you to discover the bug.

Comment: x/1000 * 38 = x * 0.038. Just sayin'

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  $tempPrice = str_replace(',',"", $price); //gets rid of "," 
  $tempPrice = substr($tempPrice,2); //removes currency from the front
  $tempPrice = floatval($tempPrice); //converts to double from string

  if($tempPrice > 500) 
  {
    echo $tempPrice*0.038;
  }
  else 
  {
    echo 'NA';
  }
 ?>
```